# Title Break in Web Intelligence Column Name

Tags: business-objects

In a previously created report is it possible to to edit the column title?
Namely, some of my columns have very long names, and I wouldn't like to make a column too wide, but I would like to break the title in a specific places.
Where and how can I do that?

Thanks!
A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by turning the column title into a formula and using the `char()` function to introduce a carriage return.

E.g.

> = "This is the first line" + char(10) + char(13) + "and this is the second line"

Comment: The thing is - the end users want to do it, and they do not how to code. I have found that right click on a column name -> format cells -> row break could solve the problem